# I would like to use simple git merge instead of git rebase, which are the differences?

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase

After I did a `git pull upstream master` command, "git" suggest me resolve the conflicts first, then `git add file` and later `git rebase --continue`.

But, I wouldn't like to use git rebase, I'd prefer git merge, it seems more cleaner for me.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Git will only suggest *continuing* a rebase if you *started* a rebase earlier. If your Git isn't too ancient, `git status` will also tell you that you're in the middle of an incomplete rebase (or merge) if you are in the middle of an incomplete rebase (or merge). You may have run a `git rebase` that you forgot about, or were unaware of because you ran it by running `git pull` with the second action for `pull` set to `rebase`.

Comment: In any case, yes, you can do a `git rebase --abort` to terminate the ongoing rebase and put everything back the way it was before you started. It would be a good idea to figure out how you got started on a rebase, though.

Comment: "Merge" and "rebase" are different commands. Do not mix them. The conflicts cannot be solved by Git, human intervention is required. This is the very definition of a conflict: changes on both branches that cannot be combined automatically.

Comment: Run `git --version` to find out just how ancient your installed Git is. If it's before Git 2.17 or so, it's pretty old. Current Git is 2.30, "modern" is about 2.23 or so at this point.

Comment: 2.29.2 sorry I've edited my post,because first I did a git pull, not a git merge, I think thats the problem because git suggest me (automatically it does)  git rebase (git rebase --continue and so on). On the other hand I've just remember that I did git pull because when I did git merge upstream master, git say that I have all up to date but it is not true, there are some differences between upstream and master and then it's because I did a git pull upstream master (my fork master).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your git configuration tells to use `rebase` on pull, which would explain why your `git pull` started a `rebase` instead of a `merge`.

---

- To stop the current `rebase` and use `merge` instead, you can run :

```
git rebase --abort         # aborts the rebase, and resets to the original commit
git merge origin/mybranch  # merge the remote branch
```

- If you want to check your `pull` settings, run :

```
git config --show-origin --get pull.rebase

# if you see that the setting is global, and you want to drop it :
git config --global --unset pull.rebase
# if you want to disable it just on that local repository :
git config pull.rebase false
```

- You can also leave the `pull` settings as they are, and use `fetch`, followed by either `merge` or `rebase` :

```
git fetch

# after inspecting the remote, run either :
git merge @{u}
# or
git rebase @{u}

# '@{u}' is a shortcut for "the upstream branch of the current branch"
```

Comment: Yes, that’s what I was guessing too.

Comment: Thank you, that git pull configuration was useful for me.